# Is there any way to pass the html tag to a function in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an html code like this in vuejs:

```
<img v-show="shouldBePrinted(tag)" src="someimage.jpg">
```

I would like to pass the tag itself (img) to the function `shouldBePrinted` to determine if it should be showed.

Is there any way to do this?

I tried with a ref like this but, in this case, I would like to avoid it:

```
<img ref="imgRef" v-show="shouldBePrinted(this.$refs.imgRef)" src="someimage.jpg">
```

Comment: What specifically does the tag tell you that you need to decide to show it or not?

Comment: Hi Bert! Some tag's properties like heigth, width, position, etc.

Comment: With respect to v-if, the element (tag) doesn't *exist* (in the DOM) until the expression evaluates to true, so I'm not sure this is going to work the way you expect.

Comment: I got your point. I already had to deal with that and, in some cases, I switched to v-show to save that case.

Comment: I am going to edit my question to consider what you said to me... thanks!

Comment: I'd move to using a component. That way, you can use the `mounted` or `beforeMount` hooks to access `$el`.

Comment: I'd agree with @Phil if you are going to use javascript to manipulate an html element and give it custom functionality, then you are basically using a web component. Might as well just use it. And in this case you are dealing with Vue, so might as well follow its conventions.